# How to use multidimensional char or string arrays in a loop

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, multidimensional-array

I'm so new to C++ and I just can't figure out how to use any multidimesional arrays. I want to do something like that:

```
input number of product: number; //the products' name can be 7 with NULL char. (max 6)
char arr[number][7];
```

That works. But when I want to do that in a for loop(i):

```
cin>>arr[i][7];
```

and I don't know what the hell is compiler doing?

I just want that:

```
arr[0][7]=apple;
arr[1][7]=orange;
```

So please how can I do that?

Comment: Since you are new you are in the position to learn good practices right from the start - use `std::vector<std::string>` for this.

Comment: Do you have a *genuine, thought-out reason* not to use a vector of strings? If not, then use a vector of strings.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I have a gut feeling that the person with the screen name _`WhoCares`_ will _not_ have a ready _genuine, though-out reason_ for that (certainly not while she `is new about c++ ... something like that`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
```

Since everybody is recommending it, I thought I'd sketch the options for you.

Note that you would have gotten this kind of answer in 10 milli-seconds by 3 different persons, **if** you had supplied a short, working sample code snippet (translating code 1:1 is more efficient than 'thinking up' examples that you *might* recognize)

Here you go:

```
std::vector<std::string> strings

strings.push_back("apple");    
strings.push_back("banana");

// or
std::string s;

std::cin >> s; // a word
strings.push_back(s);

// or
std::getline(std::cin, s); // a whole line
strings.push_back(s);

// or:
// add #include <iterator>
// add #include <algorithm>

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin),
     std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
     std::back_inserter(strings));
```

Direct addressing is also possible:

```
std::vector<std::string> strings(10); // 10 empty strings

strings[7] = "seventh";
```

**Edit** in response to comments:

```
const char* eighth = "eighth";

if (strings[7] != eighth)
{  
      // not equal
}

// If you really **must** (read, no you don't) you can get a const char* for the string:

const char* sz = strings[7].c_str(); // warning: 
         // invalidated when `strings[7]` is modified/destructed
```

Comment: hey. I cant use strcmp with that type of data? Im trying to compare that with a data from linked list: products->name . and it errors : cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int strcmp(const char*, const char*)'|

Comment: @WhoCares: I updated the answer with some more C++ style ways to work with std::string _and_ the way to interoperate with C apis. However, the `str*` family of functions is _redundant_ and **not** in C++ style. So, don't use it for that.

Answer (score 1):

Because `arr[i][7]` is a `char`, and in fact one past the last element, which means you may get memory access error.

What you want to do maybe `cin>>arr[i];`.

How ever, this is not a very good idea, as you cannot control how many characters are read from input, which will easily cause memory overrun.

The easy way would be using `std::vector<std::string>` as others have suggested.

Comment: mmmm. I had missed the fact that the first dimension was hardcoded (not `char*[]`)

Comment: it doenst work. when i input "apple" and watching the variables on watch screen it is like that: arr[i]='a' :\

Comment: `cin>>arr[i]` is a very bad idea - too much input will cause writing beyond the end of the array. You'll be better off using `std::vector<std::string>`, and writing safely into each string.

Comment: @WhoCares It worked for me for the simple program `std::cin>>arr[0];std::cout<<arr[0];`. I don't know which IDE you are using, but if it shows `'a'`, probably it is only showing the first character. A string would probably be enclosed in `""`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a real reason (which you mustn't hide from us), make as Björn says and use a vector of strings. You can even do away with the initial request for the total size:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::string> fruits;
std::string line;

while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
  fruits.push_back(line);
}
```

Let's test:

```
std::cout << "You entered the following items:\n";
for (auto const & f : fruits) std::cout << "* " << f << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a two dimensional array of `char`

```
char arr[number][7];
```

And then trying to assign a string (char* or const char*) to them which will not work. What you can do here is assign a character, for example:

```
arr[0][1] = 'a';
```

If you can I would recommend using `std::vector` and `std::string` it would make things much clearer. In your case you could do

```
cin>>arr[i];
```

But I would not recommend it as you could only store up to 6 character char* strings (plus the null terminator). You can also have an array of char*

```
char* arr[number];
```

then dynamically allocate memory to store the strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
strcpy(&arr[0], "apple");
strcpy(&arr[1], "orange");
```

but for C++ is better to use `std::vector<std::string>` for array of strings

Comment: that may works but The user will enter the products from keyboard. so what type of variable I should use? for ex: char pr; cin>>pr; strcpy(&arr[0],pr); is it works?

Comment: This would not work. You can only get one `char` at a time, the the `strcpy` is wrong.

Comment: I would go with `std::vector<std::string>` over `char[][]` when I have it available.

Comment: No :) Use std::string on start, it easy. But if still want use char arrays, you should define array, like char input[7], and use it, but if somebody enter string with length more then 6 chars it can corrupt your memory and you get segmentation fault

Comment: Saying &arr[0] is actually a compile error, at least for g++.  Say either arr[0] or &arr[0][0].

Answer (score 0):

Using std::vector and std::string will usually save you headaches once you understand them.  Since you are brand new to C++, it might be useful to understand what is going on with two-dimensional arrays anyhow.

When you say

```
char array[N][M];
```

With N and M being constants, not variables, you are telling the compiler to allocate N*M items of type char.  There will be a block of memory dedicated to that array of size N*M*sizeof(char).  (You can declare an array of anything, not just char.  Since sizeof(char) is 1, the memory will be N*M bytes long.)  If you looked at raw memory, the first byte in the memory would be where array[0][0] is.  The second byte would be where array[0][1] is, an so on, for M bytes.  Then you would see array[1][0].  This is called row-major order.

As @jbat100 mentioned, when you say array[i][j] you are referring to a single character.  When you say array[i], you are referring to the address of row i in the array.  There is no pointer actually stored in memory, but when you say array[i] the compiler knows that you mean that you want the address of row i in the array:

```
char* row_i = array[i];
```

Now if i>0, then row_i points to somewhere in the middle of that block of memory dedicated to the array.  This would do the same thing:

```
char* row_i = &array[i][0];
```

If you have a string, "orange" and you know that the length of it is less than M, you can store it in a given row in the array, like this:

```
strcpy(array[i], "orange"); // or
array[i][0] = 'o'; array[i][1] = 'a'; ... array[i][6] = 0;
```

Or you could have said row_i instead of array[i].  This copies 7 bytes into the array in the location of row_i.  The strcpy() also copies an extra byte which is a 0, and this is the convention for terminating a character string in C and C++.  So the 7 bytes are six bytes, 'o', 'r', 'a', 'n', 'g', and 'e', plus a 0 byte.  Now strcmp(row_i, "orange") == 0.

Beware that if your string is longer than M, the strcpy and the simple char assignments will not (probably) produce a compile error, but you will end up copying part of your string into the next row.

Read about pointers and arrays in a good C/C++ book.